# How to break y-axis using seaborn?

Tags: seaborn

The data points range from 0.0001 to 0.9 and the very smaller values are not actually visible on the plot. Is there a way to break y axis so that the plots are visible properly?

```
fig, plot1 = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(14, 5)
plot1 = sns.barplot(x='potato',y='mean',hue='group',data=new)
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
```

Comment: You have to adapt matplolib example: https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_axis.html